Which fields are companies required to report for 10-k filings?
For 10-k filings, which fields are companies required to report? For example:

Liabilities
Operating Expenses
Operating Income
Cash and Cash Equivalents
Property, Plant, and Equipment
Cash Flows from Operating Activities

etc.
I want to know which of these will be consistent across every 10-k report. I am building a model which uses these data.

Have you tried looking at https://www.sec.gov/files/form10-k.pdf ?

@BigMistake I am thinking your question would get better responses on either Law Stack Exchange or Personal Finance Stack Exchange.

@BigMistake I have seen 10-K where the financial information of the company is not explicitly included. In these case, the information is published elsewhere and included by reference.
